# SharePoint March CU installation problems

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, cumulative-update, psconfig

Microsoft assisted me with patching our SharePoint 2013 instance. It turns out the engineer was missing params in the command he had me run, which was this:

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -wait
```

Instead of the full thing:

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install
```

We ran into a bunch or problems, some of which were solved by running:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd secureresources
```

Next, we had issues opening office documents. I fixed this by running:

```
Install-SPApplicationContent
```

Now I am worried we might still have some other issues. Looking at the full psconfig command, I saw there are powershell equivalents for them:

```
Install-SPFeature -AllExistingFeatures
Install-SPService
Initialize-SPResourceSecurity
```

Is it safe to run these just to be sure everything was configured correctly? I would run the psconfig wizard all over again but don't want a sustained outage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to re-run these at any time. You must run these on each SharePoint server. You can always just re-execute the full psconfig command, instead. Or run the Config Wizard.